# how to send proof of paypal transaction to server for confirmation and fulfillment of transaction in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, paypal

i am displaying NSDictionary via NSlog which is resulting as
    Here is your proof of payment:

```
{
client =     {
    environment = sandbox;
    "paypal_sdk_version" = "1.0.5";
    platform = iOS;
    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
};
payment =     {
    amount = "190.50";
    "currency_code" = USD;
    "short_description" = Vegetables;
};
"proof_of_payment" =     {
    "adaptive_payment" =         {
        "app_id" = "APP-80W284485P519543T";
        "pay_key" = "AP-0W362760MW159460W";
        "payment_exec_status" = COMPLETED;
        timestamp = "2013-07-25T04:12:46.646-07:00";
    };
};
```

i have read documentations
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/
from this link i got The PayPal REST API uses the OAuth 2.0 framework for authorization. now what to do with this result to view some real flowing transactions in my paypal account (sandbox) ? what to do next? i have parsed JSON but but what to do with these values by simply storing them in variables? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when your transaction complete with Paypal you will get an "payKey"
in pay paymentSuccessWithKey delegate method. you can call your web services here to store your results to your server.

```
#pragma mark PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

-(void)paymentSuccessWithKey:(NSString *)payKey andStatus:(PayPalPaymentStatus)status; {
    paymentStatus = PAYMENTSTATUS_SUCCESS;
    NSLog(@"...payKey...........%@", payKey);
    [self performSelector:@selector(tellserverYouHavePaid:) withObject:payKey afterDelay:0.2];

}

-(void)tellserverYouHavePaid{
//call your web services here
}
```